# How can I list all the upvotes and downvotes I cast on Quora?

Tags: quora

How can I list all the *upvotes and downvotes* I cast on Quora? Quora does not have such feature, but maybe there exist some user scripts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to list all the upvotes and downvotes you cast on Quora.